# Adding number from variable to the property of an object

Tags: c++, class

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Spacecraft
{
private:
    int size;
public:
    int setSize( int new_size );
    int getSize();
    int describe();
    Spacecraft (int size);
};
int Spacecraft::setSize( int new_size)
{
    size = new_size;
    return 0;
}
Spacecraft::Spacecraft (int new_size)
{
    size = new_size;
}
int Spacecraft::getSize()
{
    return size;
}
int Spacecraft::describe()
{

    cout <<"Your spacecraft is size " (adding Customcraft.getSize() here);
    return 0;
}



int main() {
    int size;
    cout <<"Type in the size of your spacecraft: ";
    cin >>size;
        cout <<endl;

    Spacecraft Customcraft(the value of size to here);
    Customcraft.describe();




    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to put the user input into Spacecraft Customercraft (size). Which did not work so I'm wondering how would add the value of size in so the computer doesn't look at it the word but an integer value.

Would it be possible to link Customcraft.getSize() to the describe() function? When I tried to Customcraft was unrecognized. I'm new to this class stuff so please try to keep explanations at a beginner level please.

edit:  I have one last question thank you for solving my first question. At school when I put in size into spacecraft customcraft (size) eclipse didn't recognize the integer value of the variable. So could it be because of eclipse(indigo) and not Kepler?

Comment: Try that: cout << "Your spacecraft is size " << size << endl;

Comment: I'm doing an exercise and it wants me to use the describe function to output the user's input, so I'm kind forced to do this.

Comment: If we are in the business of helpful snippets: `if (std::cin >> size) { ... } else { std::cout << "failed to read 'size'\n"; }` (that is, you shall **always** verify that your input was successful).

Comment: I know, try that in your describe function.

Comment: @user2746748 You misunderstood what Kevin said.

Comment: Wooah thank you! I forgot that the describe is linked to spacecraft class so it can be recognized! Thank you!!

Comment: I have one more question for some reason the eclipse(kepler) recognized the integer value size held, but the one at school eclipse(indigo) kept giving me errors. Would it be because of eclipse version difference that caused those errors?

Answer (score 0):

you can just write :

```
cout <<"Your spacecraft is size " << size);
```